# Extruding multiple edges simultaneously but separately

Tags: modeling

Coming from C4D, I'm having a very hard time with Blender. I want to use the extrude tool to extrude several edges into not connected new edges. In Cinema 4D this could be achieved by unchecking "preserve groups". How do I do it in Blender?

Here's a short animation of what I mean:
[image: c4d vs blender extrude tool]

Comment: Try Alt+E, in face mode this will give you the option to extrude individual faces, I am not sure about edges though.

Comment: Unfortunately, that only offers an "Edges only" option in edge mode, which seems to behave the same as a regular extrusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best I could come up with is:

(i) Extrude and tapping <kbd>z</kbd> to constrain to the z-axis.  (The constraint keys combined with Transformation Orientations are well put together in Blender so you should check into those as well.)

(ii) For some reason, using Rip <kbd>v</kbd> doesn't work for the entire edge loop so I separated the Vertices a few edges at a time.

(iii)  Scaling by normals separates them without distortion <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> so once the scaling was finished I used regular scaling to bring the edges back down.(again, constrained to 'z')

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I want to do! Love that you took the time to make an animation as well.